# Change the title of the select control

Tags: winjs, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using a  control in my application and I need to localize the title.

By default it shows "CHOOSE AN ITEM". How can I change it?

I tried to set the name, the title , etc.. 
And visual studio does not give me to possibility to look at the DOM while the select control is open.

code :

```
<select>
 <option>option 1</option>
 <option>option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You are trying to do 'on the fly' Localization. There a lots of resources out there. Here are a few: [Using language dictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/tomershamam/2007/10/30/wpf-localization-on-the-fly-language-selection/) , [Using RESX files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files) , [Using ObjectDataProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22967/WPF-Runtime-Localization)

Comment: Is that what I should do? there is no way to simply set the title of if?

Comment: I'm not sure about winjs, but with something like WPF, a simple DataBinding would let you do that.

Comment: Apparently you can: [Databinding with WinJS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19622858/2596334)

Comment: I know that I can use data binding in winjs. But I don't know how to change the title of the select control. The localization part will be done after knowing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this title can be edited. The selection screen is something that comes from the OS.

Comment: Thanks. I had the same guess.